# which one give better performance and correct way to bind @Input in angular?

Tags: angular, input, angular-decorator

i can use three Input attributes as like below

```html
<sample-component [attr1]="value1" [attr2]="value2" [attr3]="value3"></sample-component>
```

or

```html
<sample-component [combinedAttr]="combinedObject"></sample-component>
```

In that combined object i am having three attributes value.

Which one is best way?
if single object is best is that single input and single output is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I think separate attribute method is much better, Let's say you want to manipulate the component by changing one attribute, the Object way, you have to have an object model for this (If only you are not creating JS objects then and there by demand which as per my knowledge a bad practice. 
So your memory gets cluttered with extra objects. And when there's change, you have to change several more palaces to add more attributes.